# Complex Analysis Estimation Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Hi there I was wondering if someone could please help me? I understand the solution of this until it gets to the Polynomial Estimation Lemma part. What is the Polynomial Estimation Lemma and how can it be applied? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What text did you get the image from if I may ask ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial estimation lemma, as I know it, states quite helpfully that, for a polynomial of the form $p(z) = a_n z^n + \dots + a_0$;
$$
\forall \epsilon \exists A,B,M \text{with} |a_n|-\epsilon < A \leq |a_n| \leq B < |a_n|+\epsilon $$
such that 
$$
|z|>M \implies A|z|^n \leq  |p(z)| \leq B|z|^n
$$
Essentially that we can approximate any polynomial by a monic polynomial of the same degree.

In this case, they seem to be choosing $A = \frac{1}{2}<1$ in the denominator. This gives, for large enough $R$, the estimate $\left|\dfrac{z^2}{z^4+\dots}\right| \leq \dfrac{R^2}{\frac 12 R^4} = \frac{2R^2}{R^4}$ as desired.

Comment: No problem- I'm actually studying for my Complex Analysis qualifying exam right now, myself.